# Import and export to Microsoft SharePoint using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharepoint

I’m building an application with flutter and I need it to be able to import csv files from Microsoft SharePoint, edit them and export them back to that SharePoint - unfortunately I cannot find any tutorials or resources on that topic, everything is just for python and SharePoint but I’m using flutter and writing in Dart :)

If someone could give me a short summary on how to do it and/or link resources it would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should be the same concept, sharepoint is just a rest api service, so any http get/post would work. it would just the request headers would be the difficult part

Comment: what do you mean with request headers? :) and thank you, so I guess I can just take any tutorial about doing this in java / python and then transfer it to my dart app